# They aren't scary but interesting

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence sounds the more natural, the first or the second? Should a comma be used in both before "but"?

1. "I like horror movies. They aren't scary for me but they are interesting."
2. "I like horror movies. They aren't scary for me but interesting."

Comment: I don't think you should use "but" there. I don't see a contrast. If you said "They are scary for me" then I could see why you'd use "but". But "but" isn't required here, or appropriate. You also mention you "like" these movies in the first sentence, so using "interesting" later on with a "but" seems kind of unusual.

Comment: @AIQ - Assuming that most horror film fans _like_ to be scared, I don't see anything wrong with using _but_. "They aren't scary for me, but [on the other hand] I find them interesting."

Comment: @Kate Bunting do my sentences sound unnatural? Should I use yours instead?

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting

Comment: @AntoniaA I'd go with the first one (not that there's anything wrong with the second one, it just sounds more natural to me)

Comment: The ellipsis in the second one is perfectly good, but a little more of a written style than the first one.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak I didn't use a comma before "but". Should I add it in both sentences?

Comment: Optional in both cases. More common to include it in the first one (because of the explicit subject).

Comment: @Luke Sawczak Is it optional here too? " Do you like horror movies? Yes, because they aren't scary for me, but they are interesting."

Comment: I find it very odd that you all think that is a fine sentence. I've never heard anyone use that phrasing. @KateBunting Would you ever say it like that? Exactly like that? *"They aren't scary for me but they are interesting."* is not a natural phrasing (considering the context of course). This is more natural: *"I like horror movies. They don't scare me. But I still find them interesting."*

"

Comment: @KateBunting See OP's post and comments from native speakers here in WordReference: [They aren't scary but interesting](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/they-arent-scary-but-interesting.3880355/).

Comment: OP, I totally agree with the feedback you got in WordRef.

Comment: @KateBunting *Assuming that most horror film fans **like** to be scared* - OK. Sure. Let's assume OP is one of these fans who like to be scared. So, scared == interesting. But OP says the movies don't scare them. So how can a not-scary movie be interesting to a fan who likes to be scared? I think OP needs "still" in there after "but". *They are not scary for me [but I want them to be], but I still find them interesting [even though I should be bored because there are not scary].*

Comment: @AIQ - I'm not at all interested in horror films; I was just surprised by your assertion that _but_ was completely wrong here. I understood Antonia's sentence to mean "Despite not being scared by horror movies, I still find them interesting".

Comment: Antonia - I find (1) quite acceptable (with emphasis on the _are_) - (2) not so much. My paraphrase was meant to show why I thought _but_ was OK.